# Error when injecting dependency into main module

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to inject a dependency into my my main module,

```
module app {
    angular.module("movie",
        ["common.services"]);
}
```

This creates the error:

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

If I comment out the dependecy the app loads fine.

```
module app {
    angular.module("movie",
        [/*"common.services"*/]);
}
```

And this is the "common.service" I'm injecting:

```
module app.common {
    angular.module("common.services",
        ["ngResources"]);
}
```

Looking at the docs page it states:

> This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception

So it looks like the `common.services` module isn't loading.

In my index I have this:

```
<!--Libraries-->
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!--Controllers-->
<script src="app/movieCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/movieSearchCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/movieListCtrl.js"></script>
<!--Services-->
<script src="app/services/common.services.js"></script>
```

So the common.services file is being loaded after the app.js. So where's the error comming from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not familiar with typescript but shouldn't your service be

```
module common.services {
    angular.module("common.services",
        ["ngResources"]);
}
```

rather than **module app.common** ?